# How to create a group of UI elements that you are able to iterate through

Tags: c++, qt

I have an application I am making as a project for a class, which contains the game hangman and others.
 
I have a Line Edit input field for the user to guess a letter. This input is restricted to 1 letter. 
 I want to have a for loop that checks if the users input matches any letters from the games target word, and if it does it places that letter on the screen. 
I have a bunch of labels that I plan on putting a single letter in, each arranged to correspond with the letters placement in the correct word string.
**How do I put a qt ui elements into a data structure so that I can access them in a for loop?** 
Here is some code I tried after looking online, to give you an idea of what I'm trying to do.

```
int Hangman::check_input(QString input){

    QList<QObject *> visible_word = {ui->label_0, ui->label_1,ui->label_2, ui->label_3,ui->label_4};
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < current_word.length(); i++){
        if (input == current_word[i]){
            ui->visible_word[i]->text() == current_word[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with the code you have, let's fix it so that it has a correct method signature, and so that it compiles:

```
/// Returns the number of newly matched letters.
int Hangman0::check_input(QChar input) {
   int matched{};
   std::array<QLabel*, 5> visible_word = {ui->label_0, ui->label_1,ui->label_2, ui->label_3,ui->label_4};
   for (int i{}; i < current_word.length(); i++) {
      auto const ch = current_word.at(i);
      if (input == ch && visible_word[i]->text() != ch) {
         visible_word[i]->setText(ch);
         ++ matched;
      }
   }
   return matched;
}
```

But there's little point to enumerating those Ui elements manually, nor to manually inserting them into the layout in the Ui file. Instead, leave the Ui file with an empty layout, and insert the elements programmatically as needed. First, let's approximate the uic output from a minimal `.ui` file:

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/hangman-42261596
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <forward_list>

namespace Ui { // Approximate uic output
struct Hangman {
   QFormLayout * topLayout;
   QHBoxLayout * lettersLayout;
   QLineEdit * letterEntry;
   QPushButton * setup;
   void setupUi(QWidget * widget) {
      topLayout = new QFormLayout{widget};
      topLayout->addRow(lettersLayout = new QHBoxLayout);
      topLayout->addRow("Guess", letterEntry = new QLineEdit);
      letterEntry->setMaxLength(1);
      topLayout->addRow(setup = new QPushButton{"Setup"});
   }
};
}
```

Then, let's design a basic `Hangman` game widget. We can keep the letter labels by value in a `std::forward_list` - this makes life relatively easy and we don't have to deal with explicit memory management of any kind.

```
class Hangman : public QWidget {
   Q_OBJECT
   Ui::Hangman ui;
   QString m_currentWord;
   std::forward_list<QLabel> m_letters;
public:
   explicit Hangman(QWidget * parent = nullptr) :
      QWidget{parent}
   {
      ui.setupUi(this);
      connect(ui.letterEntry, &QLineEdit::returnPressed, [this]{
         auto const text = ui.letterEntry->text();
         if (!text.isEmpty())
            checkInput(text[0]);
      });
      connect(ui.setup, &QPushButton::clicked, [this]{
         setWord(QInputDialog::getText(this, "Setup", "Secret word:",
                                       QLineEdit::Normal, m_currentWord)); // a hack
      });
      setWord("Hello");
   }
   void setWord(const QString & word) {
      m_currentWord = word.toUpper();
      m_letters.clear();
      auto letter = m_letters.before_begin();
      for (int i{}; i < word.size(); ++i) {
         letter = m_letters.emplace_after(letter);
         letter->setFrameShape(QFrame::Box);
         ui.lettersLayout->addWidget(&*letter);
      }
   }
   int checkInput(QChar input) {
      int matched{};
      input = input.toUpper();
      auto letter = m_letters.begin();
      for (int i{}; i < m_currentWord.size(); ++i) {
         if (m_currentWord.at(i) == input) {
            letter->setText(input);
            matched ++;
         }
         letter ++;
      }
      return matched;
   }
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
   QApplication app{argc, argv};
   Hangman hangman;
   hangman.show();
   return app.exec();
}
#include "main.moc"
```

Answer (score 2):

What you've done works, and assuming English, since the number of possible letters is likely fixed at 26 (unless you're allowing non alphabetical characters for some reason), there's really nothing wrong with it. It's only problematic if the number of labels is variable or huge, and neither situation seems to be the case here.

What you can also do is use the `findChildren` method, and there are several variations on that. The easiest one is if all of your labels are parented to the same widget and there are no other `QLabel` instances under that same parent:

```
QList <QLabel *> parent->findChildren <QLabel *> ();
```

Otherwise, you'd probably need to use the variation that accepts a regular expression to match child names:

```
QList <QLabel *> parent->findChildren <QLabel *> (QRegExp ("^label_"));
```

Note that the order in both cases may not be what you want for populating your labels with the chosen letters. The documentation doesn't say, but I believe the order that's returned reflects the order that the children were created in. Since you created them in Qt Designer, that order may not be reliable; for instance, if you missed number 12 in the middle and added it after the others, then label_12 will be last in the list. That may or may not matter depending on the rest of your approach. If you need your list to be in the order of label 0, label 1, and so forth, then your current mechanism is probably what you want.

It seems brute force, and it is, but sometimes that's perfectly acceptable.